# Gradient descent optimization

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

I am trying to understand gradient descent optimization in ML(machine learning) algorithms. I understand that there's a cost function—where the aim is to minimize the error $\hat y-y$. In a scenario where weights $w_1, w_2$ are being optimized to give the minimum error, and partial derivatives are being used, does it change both $w_1$ and $w_2$ in each step or is it a combination (e.g., in few iterations only $w_1$ is changed and when $w_1$ isn't reducing the error any more, the derivative starts with $w_2$)? The application could be a linear regression model, a logistic regression model, or boosting algorithms.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Gradient descent updates all parameters at each step. You can see this in the update rule:

$$
w^{(t+1)}=w^{(t)} - \eta\nabla f\left(w^{(t)}\right).
$$

Since the gradient of the loss function $\nabla f(w)$ is vector-valued with dimension matching that of $w$, all parameters are updated at each iteration.

The learning rate $\eta$ is a positive number that re-scales the gradient. [Taking too large a step can endlessly bounce you across the loss surface with no improvement in your loss function; too small a step can mean tediously slow progress towards the optimum.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364360/how-can-change-in-cost-function-be-positive)

[Although you could estimate linear regression parameters using gradient descent, it's not a good idea.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160179/do-we-need-gradient-descent-to-find-the-coefficients-of-a-linear-regression-mode/164164#164164)

[Likewise, there are better ways to estimate logistic regression coefficients.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344309/why-using-newtons-method-for-logistic-regression-optimization-is-called-iterati)

Comment: So the algorithm may try different combinations like increase `w1` , decrease `w2` based on the direction from partial derivative to reach local minima and just to confirm the algorithm will not necessarily give the global minima always?

Comment: and does the partial derivative also help to explain how much increase or decrease has to be done to `w1` and `w2` or that is done by learning rate/shrinkage while partial derivative only provides direction of descent?

Comment: The gradient is a vector, so it gives a direction **and** a magnitude. A vector can be arbitrarily rescaled by a positive scalar and it will have the same direction, but the rescaling will change its magnitude.

Comment: If magnitude is also given by the gradient then what is the role of shrinkage or learning rate?

Comment: The learning rate rescales the gradient. Suppose $\nabla f(x)$ has a large norm (length). Taking a large step will move you to a distant part of the loss surface (jumping from one mountain to another). The core justification of gradient descent is that it's a linear approximation in the vicinity of $w^{(t)}$. That approximation is always inexact, but it's probably worse the farther away you move -- hence, you want to take small steps, so you use some small $\eta$, where 'small' is entirely problem-specific.

Answer (score 7):

> When the optimization does occur through partial derivatives, in each turn does it change both w1 and w2 or is it a combination like in few iterations only w1 is changed and when w1 isn't reducing the error more, the derivative starts with w2 - to reach the local minima?

In each iteration, the algorithm will change all weights at the same time based on gradient vector. In fact, the gradient is a vector. The length of the gradient is as same as number of the weights in the model.

On the other hand, changing one parameter at a time did exist and it is called [**coordinate decent algorithm**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent), which is a type of **gradient free optimization algorithm**. In practice, it may not work as well as gradient based algorithm.

Here is an interesting answer on gradient free algorithm

[Is it possible to train a neural network without backpropagation?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235862/is-it-possible-to-train-a-neural-network-without-backpropagation)

Answer (score 2):

Gradient decent is applied to both `w1` and `w2` for each iteration. During each iteration, the parameters updated according to the gradients. They would likely have different partial derivative.

Check [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/06/24/gradient-descent-linear-regression).

Answer (score 1):

The aim of gradient descent is to minimize the cost function.  This minimization is achieved by adjusting weights, for your case w1 and w2.  In general there could be **n** such weights.

Gradient descent is done in the following way:

1. initialize weights randomly.
2. compute the cost function and gradient with initialized weights.
3. update weigths:
       It might happen that the gradient is O for some weights, in that case 
       those weights doesn't show any change after updating.
       for example:  Let say gradient is [1,0]  the **W2** will remain 
       unchanged.
4. check the cost function with updated weights, if the decrement is acceptable enough continue the iterations else terminate.

while updating weights which weight ( W1 or W2) gets changed is entirely decided by gradient. All the weights get updated ( some weights might not change based on gradient).

Comment: "if the decrement is acceptable enough continue the iterations else terminate", is there a default value which is applied in packages of python ( `sklearn`) or R packages such as `caret`? It can be user specified only in a manually created gradient descent function?