# Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares, (Logistic Regression)

Tags: r, regression, logistic, optimization, likelihood

I'm trying to obtain the parameters estimates in a *Logistic Regression* using the IRLS (Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares) algorithm.

I'm following this great and simple reference slides: ([Logistic Regression](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/stats/stats200/stats200.1172/Lecture26.pdf))

And also this question where there are all the mathematic details and codes: [Why using Newton's method for logistic regression optimization is called iterative re-weighted least squares?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/344309/why-using-newtons-method-for-logistic-regression-optimization-is-called-iterati)

I'm trying to obtain the estimates, without using the `lm` function, but using the matrix notation,as stated in the question I mentioned above:

$$
b^{(m+1)} = b^{(m)} + (X^T W_{(m)} X)^{-1}X^T W_{(m)} z_{(m)} 
$$

- the predictor is equal to (in the code case we don't have the intercept): $\eta_i = \sum_{j=1}^{2}\beta_jx_{ij}=\beta_1x_{i1}+\beta_{i2}x_{i2}$
- As stated in the first link above $W$ is a diagonal matrix, where each element of the diagonal is the second partial derivative in respect of the vector of parameters $\beta$ of fitted values of the Logistic Regression [image]
- the residual $z =\frac{y_i - E[y_i]}{h'(\eta_i)}$ where $h'(\eta_n)$ is the first partial derivative of the fitted values in respect of the vector of the same parameters, and it is equal to $h'(\eta) = \frac{1}{1+e^\eta}*(1-\frac{1}{1+e^\eta})$

In the code below we have

The `p = 2` is the variable to set the number of parameters (in this example it's not use the intercept).

The `n = 20` is the variable to set the number of observation.

The code (the first part is copied from the question link above) of the algorithm in matrix notation is not working (*estimates do not converge*) when we have large matrices (i.e. when we have `p = 3`the matrix notation algorithm never converges, when we have `p =2` and `n = 200` the algorithm never converges.
In the matrix form algorithm, also the convergence is much slower than the algorithm with `lm` function.

By the way all the elements before the IRLS is computed (estimation of vector of betas parameters) are equal in both forms, and I also added two lists to show that are equal.
This below is the code:

```
#LOGISTIC REGRESSION Estimation (IRLS)
#LOGIT

set.seed(5)
p <- 2             ##for p > 3 the estimates do not converge
n <- 20
x <- matrix(rnorm(n * p), n, p)
betas <- runif(p, -2, 2)
hc <- function(x) 1 /(1 + exp(-x)) # inverse canonical link
p.true <- hc(x %*% betas)
y <- rbinom(n, 1, p.true)
tol=1e-8




#IRLS using the 'lm' function:
b.init = rep(1,p)
b.old <- b.init
change <- Inf


IRLS_canoni_ = list()


while(change > tol) {
  eta <- x %*% b.old  # linear predictor

  y.hat <- hc(eta)
  h.prime_eta <- y.hat * (1 - y.hat)     #first derivative
  z <- (y - y.hat) / h.prime_eta

  b.new <- b.old + lm(z ~ x - 1, weights = h.prime_eta)$coef  # WLS regression
  change <- sqrt(sum((b.new - b.old)^2))
  b.old <- b.new

  IRLS_canoni_$eta = cbind(IRLS_canoni_$eta,eta)
  IRLS_canoni_$y.hat = cbind(IRLS_canoni_$y.hat,y.hat)
  IRLS_canoni_$h.prime_eta = cbind(IRLS_canoni_$h.prime_eta, h.prime_eta)
  IRLS_canoni_$z = cbind(IRLS_canoni_$z, z)
  IRLS_canoni_$b.old = cbind(IRLS_canoni_$b.old, b.old)

  print(b.old)
  Sys.sleep(.1)

}

b.old


my_IRLS_canonical(x, y, rep(1,p), hc)    
glm(y ~ x - 1, family=binomial())$coef      #model with no intercept

glm1 = glm(y ~ x, family=binomial())







##Trying to obtain same results with matrix notation (IRLS):
deriv2 = function(x) exp(x)/(1+exp(x))^2     #second derivative


b.init = rep(1,p)
b.old1 <- b.init
change1 <- Inf


IRLS_matrix = list()

while(change1 > tol) {

  eta1 <- x %*% b.old1  # linear predictor
  y.hat1 <- hc(eta1)
  h.prime_eta1 <- y.hat1 * (1 - y.hat1)
  z1 <- (y - y.hat1) / h.prime_eta1


  Wdiag = deriv2(eta)
  W = matrix(0,n,n)
  diag(W) = Wdiag

  H = -(t(x)%*%(W)%*%x)      #not using it

  b.new1 = b.old1 + ((solve(t(x) %*% W %*% x)) %*% (t(x)%*%W%*%z1))
  change1 = sqrt(sum((b.new1 - b.old1)^2))
  b.old1 = b.new1

  IRLS_matrix$eta = cbind(IRLS_matrix$eta, eta1)
  IRLS_matrix$y.hat = cbind(IRLS_matrix$y.hat, y.hat1)
  IRLS_matrix$h.prime_eta = cbind(IRLS_matrix$h.prime_eta, h.prime_eta1)
  IRLS_matrix$z = cbind(IRLS_matrix$z, z1)
  IRLS_matrix$b.old = cbind(IRLS_matrix$b.old, b.old1)

  print(b.new1)
  Sys.sleep(.1)

}

b.new1

glm(y ~ x - 1, family=binomial())$coef    #model with no intercept


IRLS_canoni_$eta[,1] == IRLS_matrix$eta[,1]
IRLS_canoni_$y.hat[,1] == IRLS_matrix$y.hat[,1]
IRLS_canoni_$h.prime_eta[,1] == IRLS_matrix$h.prime_eta[,1]
IRLS_canoni_$z[,1] == IRLS_matrix$z[,1]

IRLS_canoni_$b.old[,1] == IRLS_matrix$b.old[,1]
```

So can anyone give a try? It seems it only works with max $2$ parameters and few observation.

Anyway I think the algorithm is correct, if it wouldn't be, it wouldn't find the correct value anytime (and this is not the case).

Why is it happening this? Thank You.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236676/can-you-give-a-simple-intuitive-explanation-of-irls-method-to-find-the-mle-of-a/237384#237384

Comment: I've read your answer. What i notice that you are giving weights (in your cauchy example) w=densityf()/firstderiv(densityf()). So basically in "my code" I setted the diagonal elements of diagonal matrix w = secondderivative. Should i change those? I don't have other ideas. Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found that inside the algorithm in the "matrix form" the variable it's equal to `Wdiag = deriv2(eta)` so in this case this variable stays always the same.

So we have to change it to `Wdiag = deriv2(eta1)`. So now both of these algorithms works fine.

There's another error anyway with this algorithm (this is also present in the original question, linked above):

- The betas starting values are all equal to $1$ as we can see it in the variable `b.init = rep(1,p)`, in this case we can't estimate much parameters (eg. if we have 8 parameters to estimate the algorithm doesn't converge in both forms) and the algorithm converge only with few parameters and observation.

**Solution**: We need to change the initialization of the betas with $0$ in this way `b.init = rep(0,p)`.

This reminds me of Non-Stationarity in time-series: when we have a parameter that is equal or bigger than $1$ the process is said to be an *explosive process*.
Since this is a sort of process that evolves in time i think that the `b.init = rep(1,p)` leads to the *non convergence path*. This is just an idea btw, but the code works fine.