# Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares - Weights Confusion

Tags: regression, logistic, binomial-distribution, weighted-regression, irls

In performing Iteratively Reweighted Least Squares (IRLS) to derive $\hat{\beta}$ estimates for logistic regression, all the resource I've read online say to use weights inversely proportional to the variance of each $Y_i$. For example, see step 4, below (taken from [here](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Edgillen/STAT211/Handouts/lecture8.pdf)):

[image]

However, in R code implementations of IRLS I've found online, the weights are set as the variance, not the inverse of the variance (e.g. [here](https://m-clark.github.io/models-by-example/newton-irls.html) or [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448061/iteratively-reweighted-least-squares-logistic-regression)).

For example, see the below image. It sets `s = mu * (1 - mu)`, which is the variance given that $Y$ in logistic regression has a Bernoulli distribution. So when the weights matrix, `S`, is calculated, shouldn't it be `S = diag(1/s)` instead of `S = diag(s)`? What am I missing here?

[image]

Having this clarified would be very helpful. I know that for weighted least squares, $w_i = \dfrac{1}{\sigma_i^2}$ is standard, so why does the weight matrix in IRLS implementations not invert the variance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The IWLS algorithm for generalised linear models is different from that for a heteroscedastic linear model because it accounts for two things:

- the non-linear link function
- the variance-mean relationship

The likelihood score equations look like
$$\frac{d\mu}{d\beta}\frac{1}{V(\mu)}(Y-\mu)=0$$
so the variance is in the denominator, as you expect. We can expand ${d\mu}/{d\beta}$:
$$\frac{d\eta}{d\beta}\frac{d\mu}{d\eta}\frac{1}{V(\mu)}(Y-\mu)=0$$
and $d\eta/d\beta$ is just $X^T$, so
$$X^T\frac{d\mu}{d\eta}\frac{1}{V(\mu)}(Y-\mu)=0$$

We want to define a new response variable $Z$ and weight variable $W$ so that the WLS equations
$$X^TW(Z-X\beta)=0$$
match the likelihood equations.  This is done with

- *working response* $Z=(Y-X\beta)\frac{d\eta}{d\mu}$, which is a first-order approximation to transforming $Y$ with the link function
- *working weights* $W=(\frac{d\mu}{d\eta})^2\frac{1}{V(\mu)}$

Note that the variance is still in the denominator. However, for the so-called *canonical* link function for each distribution, it so happens that $d\mu/d\eta=V(\mu)$ and the working weights are equal to $V(\mu)^2V(\mu)^{-1}=V(\mu)$. That is, it looks as though the variance has been put in the numerator instead.

You can see the variance is *really* going in the denominator by looking at the IWLS algorithm for non-canonical links, such as the identity link for a binomial or Poisson model, where $d\mu/d\eta=1$.

Comment: This is a very straightforward and clear answer, thank you!